# Shiny using the selectizeInput load(query, callback) configuration

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am looking to use the `selectizeInput()` input control to allow a user to search for an address using the google API, so when a user starts typing an address into the control, the `selectizeInput()` function will then return a list of addresses, very similar to the Google Maps address search box.

I have found notes on the selectize.js [GitHub](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md), possibly using the `load(query, callback)` option to call the Google API using Javascript. However, I am a complete novice with Javascript so unsure how to go about this, and even whether its possible using the Shiny implementation of selectize.

Any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you displaying a Google map also? If so, `library(googleway); google_map(key = "your_api_key", search_box = TRUE)` will give you the address search box inside the map

Comment: No, I am using a leaflet map. I currently have a text box that allows a user to enter an address, which uses JQuery to query to google API and return the geolocation (Which I then use to display a bunch of information on the leaflet map). Ideally, the textbox should only accept valid addresses, hence the need for something similar to selectizeInput().

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out eventually.

Using the documentation [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/building-inputs.html), built a custom input object through Javascript, which I was then able to take advantage of the Google Maps Javascript API.